# Ignore empty values in dictionary (from large .cdt file) Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to find a way to ignore the empty inputs from a large dictionary. The data comes from a .cdt file- it was originally excel but is now in text format. I've tried a few fixes and nothing works. I'm going to be finding minimum and maximum inputs and standard deviations of each of the elements of this dictionary, but I need to make sure all the empty entries are ignored first.

This is the code I'm using to pick out and print the specific variables I want. Any pointers in the right direction would really be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
planets = {}

with open ('planets.csv', 'r') as f:

    for line in f :

        line = line.strip("\n ' '")
        line = line.split(",")
        name = line[1]

        exop = {'Host Name' : line[1],
                'Planet Letter' : line[2],
                'Discovery Method' : line[3],
                'Number of Planets in System' : line[4],
                'Orbital Period [days]' : line[5],
                'Orbit Semi-Major Axis [AU]' : line[6],
                'Eccentricity' : line[7],
                'Inclination[deg]' : line[8],
                'Planets Mass of M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]' : line[9],
                'Planets Mass of M*sin(i) Provenance]' : line[10],
                'Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]' : line[11],
                'Planet Density [g/cm**3]' : line [12],
                'TTV Flag' : line [13],
                'Kepler Field Flag' : line[14],
                'K2 Mission Flag' : line[15],
                'Number of Notes' : line[16],
                'Distance [pc]' : line[21]
                'Effective Temparature [k]' : line[25]}
        print exop
        print exop['Distance [pc]'] 
f.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to stick with filtering the dictionaries at the end. This is because if you check `line` for any empty values and, say, `line[24]` (which is never used) was empty but none of the others, then you would end up discarding valid data.

Empty strings are falsey, but so is the numerical value `0`. I've written a list comprehension that should only discard items from your final list in the case of an empty string and not zero values.

```
list_of_dicts = []

for x in range(4):
    list_of_dicts.append({'a': 123, 
                          'b': 'hello',
                          'c': 0
                          })

# Bad entry
list_of_dicts.append({'a': 123, 
                      'b': '',
                      'c': 456
                     })


# Rebuild without bad entries
new_list_of_dicts = [dictionary for dictionary in list_of_dicts 
                    if all(str(data[1]) for data in dictionary.items())] # The logic to catch empty strings

print(list_of_dicts)
print('\n')
print(new_list_of_dicts)
```

Comment: What is item in this context?

Comment: @Abbstract edited. Basically I have a list of dictionaries, and I discard those dictionaries if they have, anywhere, a value of `''`

Comment: This now gives me an output of:

abby@R2-D2:~/Documents$ python alt.py
{'Effective Temperature [k]': 'c', 'Distance [pc]': 'V', 'Host Name': '4'}


['Effective Temperature [k]', 'Distance [pc]', 'Host Name']

----------------------------------------------------------------For the variables distance and temperature I'm trying to get it to list all the data (about 200 values) without printing the empty spaces i.e. there are some temperatures not given and at the moment it will just print a blank space- I want it to ignore those. I'm very confused about what this new output means, sorry!

Comment: @Abbstract I'm not clear on where you're referring to blank spaces in that output? Note that half of that output is a dictionary and half of it is a list. Unless you can give an example of the input I'm not sure anyone can help.

Comment: @Abbstract are you suggesting that in cases where there is no output for `Effective Temperature` the value still contains the unit of measurement `c`? That is not a blank space.